# Date Formatting is not working in android?

Tags: android, simpledateformat, android-date

I have created a method to format date to "dd-MMM-yyyy" which is :

```
public String formatDate(String day, String month, String year) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.valueOf(day));
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.valueOf(month));
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.valueOf(year));
        return df.format(c.getTime());
    }
```

I am calling this method like `formatDate("12","10","2014")` and getting result `12-Oct-2015`.I am not able to understand why is it returning me year **2015** instead of **2014**.Please help

Comment: It will return "12-Nov-2014" not "12-Oct-2015".month 0 for the january

Comment: It's returning 12-Oct-2015

Comment: Check : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH

Comment: Why not use new GregorianCalendar(theYear, theMonth, theDay) ?

Comment: Also, **why** do you do all these **conversions**? It's **faster** if you use **int**s for your parameters and don't use `Integer.valueOf()` to convert them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably because months in `Calendar` starts from 0 and from 1. Try passing `11`, or better `Calendar.DECEMBER` for december. You can find [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#UNDECIMBER) the documentation

Answer (score 2):

I tried it right now and the return value for `formatDate("12", "10", "2014")` is  `12-Nov-2014`,
because `MONTH` starts with 0.

Just use `c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.valueOf(month-1));` and you should be fine